# Try Except Python, functions doesnt get read?

Tags: python

i am a beginner with python and i have the following problem.I want to create a code that takes 3 inputs separated by comma but at the same time these inputs must be int,str,int/float .I have created a function(check) that returns True if those creteria are met.nevertheless it seems that when i insert this line inside the 'try' ,nothing happens.So i can get a answer 10 for the name.

```
    while True:
        
        try:
            aa, name, note = [x for x in input("insert the following aa,name,note :\n").split(',')]
            check(aa,name,note )==True

        except:
            print("Please insert the data with the following format : aa,name,note")
            continue

        else:
            break
```

Comment: Your code looks rather nonsensical. Could you also show that `check()` function?

Comment: **Never** use `except` without naming a specific exception type (and, unless you're very sure about what you're doing, storing that exception in a variable). When you do `except:` instead of `except Exception as e:`, you give up all ability to find out exactly what went wrong by logging `e`, _and_ you stop ctrl+c to exit your program from working as-intended.

Comment: Beyond that, a [mre] would require code we can run without changes to see the same problem. Providing our own `check` function would count as a change. Similarly, a better reproducer would hardcode a specific value that's known to misbehave instead of using `input()` and running the risk that the person trying to repro the problem enters a value that behaves differently from yours.

Comment: The line `check(aa, name, note) == True` produces a boolean, but doesn't *do* anything with it. You probably want to either `assert` it, or use it for an `if`, or assign it to a variable that you use as the condition for the `while` loop.

Comment: Are you expecting `check(...) == True` to raise an exception if it's not true? It won't. It just produces the value `False` which is ignored.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score -2):

as been said earlier this is not a great practice to just leave except blank. also you can just use  because you're using bool function, but if you really want to use exceptions you can try this;

```py
while True:
        
        try:
            aa, name, note = [x for x in input("insert the following aa,name,note :\n").split(',')]
            assert(check(aa,name,note)) # assert will throw exception if argument is False

        except:
            print("Please insert the data with the following format : aa,name,note")
            continue

        else:
            break
```